# Possible to make path relative in WEB-INF/web.xml?

Tags: java, web-applications, file-upload, primefaces

1. In my `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, an upload path is set absolutely.
2. Can I make this relative to the application root?
3. Or is there a better "best practices" approach to configuring paths for file uploads?
4. Below is the relevant config code.
   *[entire config file](http://pastie.org/8016488)*

---

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/webapp/mdjdreview/upload/temp</param-value>
    </init-param>        
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make it a relative path, and use `new File(path)` to access the directory, it will be relative to the directory from which your container is started.

You can do it, but except for making it more difficult to know where the files are actually stored, and for risking to look at the wrong place because the container is started from elsewhere, I don't really see the point.

If waht you plan to do is storing the uploaded files in the directory of the deployed webapp, then you should definitely not do that, as a redeploy of the webapp will remove all the uploaded files. Treat the webapp directory as read-only.